# Include a smarter computer opponent to existing android game?

Tags: android, automation, artificial-intelligence, apk

I'm very interested in AI. I have the idea to integrate my own AI into a game trying to beat the exisiting computer opponent by simulating the user.
But what is the easiest method to integrate my AI into an existing APK?

I have four different idea:

1. Modifiying the game itself: Decompile the gamecode, add my AI code and recompile it. (Code Injection)
2. Write a special AI app as a service calling internal functions of the game. Is this even possible on Android?
3. Write a special AI app as a service sending TouchEvents to the game as user input and taking screenshots for calculating the next move.
4. Implement the AI into a Monkeyrunner script. I know that this is possible, but I prefer a method running on the device itself.

I would be very happy if there is someone who could give me an advice which idea is the most promising one and which idea is impossible to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, 1 is probably illegal and 2 and 3 are not possible.  Looks like you've got a narrower choice than you thought!  Of course, the best option is the one you didn't provide - write you own!

Comment: Option 3 is possible, it's just very complicated and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Writing my own game doesn't allow me to challenge the existing AI (that's what I want).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that 1 probably requires you get permission first from the game's author, which is probably difficult.

Comment: Before discussing any permissions, I would like to know, whether it is even possible or praticable. Because only if the first idea is the most promising one, I would have to think about a permission.

Answer (score 0):

I would use option #3!

If you create an app signed with the platform certificate you may use the INJECT_EVENTS permission and inject events on any application:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INJECT_EVENTS